# Adding a float default value in stored procedure but it says that it expect parameter

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, insert

I am trying to input a tuple of room here is my code for insert

```
create proc spInsertToRoom
@room_name varchar(50),
@room_status varchar(50)='Available',
@room_rate float
AS
BEGIN
INSERT INTO tblRoom(room_name,room_status,room_rate)
SELECT @room_name,@room_status,@room_rate
END
```

I want the status to be automaticly available. Then when I input a value
it just keeps on saying

```
exec [spInsertToRoom]'A102',3500
```

> Procedure or function 'spInsertToRoom' expects parameter '@room_rate',
>   which was not supplied.

But when I try this

> exec [spInsertToRoom]'A103',@room_rate=4000

It worked!

I'm Just wondering why is it needed to to input the `@room_rate=4000` whereas what I saw on youtube is a person just input a variable just like my former code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you need to name the parameters in your call. With your code what is happening is it will implicitly convert 3500 to varchar(50) and then not find a value for room_rate.

```
exec [spInsertToRoom] @room_name = 'A102', @room_rate = 3500
```

I would make a couple recommendations. First is not to use float when you want the number to be precise. Float is an approximate datatype. Something like NUMERIC(9, 2) would be a better choice.

My second recommendation is to drop the prefix from your names. It is just noise when looking for a procedure name and it isn't likely to get confused with something else. If that were my system the name for this proc would be Room_Insert. That way the procs will sort by the object they are dealing with and the verb is at the end. Room_Update, Room_Delete etc will all be next to other in the list of procedures when sorted alphabetically (like in SSMS).

Comment: Thank you! And thanks to your recommendation also! :)